# Google protobuf parsefromstring returns false

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to send a message on wire with the following protobuf structure

```
message TestMsg {
    string status = 1;
}
```

I create an instance of TestMsg and set status as empty and serialize it to a string.

```
TestMsg m1;
m1.set_status("");

std::string str = m1.SerializeAsString();
```

Post serialization, str is sent over wire and tried to be parsed. ParseFromString returns false whereas it should not. For any other value, it parses successfully.

```
TestMsg m2;
m2.ParseFromString(str);  <----- this returns false
```

Also, if I try to retrieve the value of m2.status(), it will return an empty string even though the parsing returns false.

I was expecting the protobuf to parse it successfully

Comment: This happens only while transmission is on wire. The warning is not seen when serialization and parsing are done in the same node/scope.